# Is there any method to fix the label truncate issue in SSRS 3D pie Chart?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I built SSRS report using 3D Pie Char style. Some reason some of the text for series label truncate. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: As far as I know there is no real limit on the length of the text, it just depends on the space available. Can you share a sample of data and a screen shot of the design and output you are currently getting.

Comment: I add the text as a tool tip so users can hover and see the whole name if the label is truncated.